# Merge cells and sum their values

Tags: excel

So I have a spreadsheet that needs some cleanup work. 
For example I need to combine these three rows into a single row. Obviously I'll have to do the name by hand, but I was hoping there was some way I could select each column of three cells and merge them all into a single cell. EG take this data

```
 HS Class of 1969 Reunion Committee 1   2   10          
 HS Class of 1969 reunion Committee 1   1   12          
 HS Class of 1969 reunion committee             1   2   10
```

and get

```
 HS Class of 1969 Reunion Committee 2   3   22  1   2   10
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Subtotal is an alternative to a PT, say with the addition of a helper columnA populated with `=IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=2,A1+1,A1)` then converted with Paste Special to Values.